# Redirect to another server without changing my current Url

Tags: c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible in c# or Jq to redirect the user to an url which is in another server (so server.transfer does not work).

What i need to do is:

- send the user from A to B(other server).
- show in the browser for the user A URL.

I can not find how to redirect to the url but without changing the name in the browser.

Is there a way in C# ASP.Net or jQuery?

Thank you!

Comment: Open a full size iframe with the url of server B ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: because I send the user to our documentation but it is in another server and we want to show the current one so he knows he is still with us.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this programatically. Here's some good info on Domain Masking, which I believe is the only way to accomplish what you are trying to do.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_masking

Comment: Please don't use link only answer. Please provide some example with context. In the future the link may not work, and your answer would be useless